# Getting null for Json data on controller side

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, submit, forms

I've got this html

```
<form action="/Cabinet/Inbox" id="frmCabinet" method="post"/>
     <input type="hidden" id="hdnSearchOptions" name="searchOptions" />
     <input onclick="inbox()"/>
</form>
```

and I have a function where I gather info from variety of DOM elements and store them in a wrapper object and then do a submit:

```
function inbox(){
  searchOptions={};
  searchOptions.SearchText=$('#txtSearch').val();
  $('#hdnSearchOptions').val(JSON.stringify(searchOptions));
  $('#frmCabinet').submit();
}
```

Here's the Inbox method on the server side:

```
public ActionResult(SearchOptions searchOptions){
   //code goes here
}


public class SearchOptions{
   public string SearchText{get;set;}
   //some more properties
}
```

When submit takes place I get null for the `searchOptions` parameter. I've tried to set enctype of the form to any possible value, I've even tried `appication/json` as per [this W3C document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/) to no avail. When I look at the value of the hidden element just before submit I see it's like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSearchOptions" name="searchOptions" value="{&quot;SearchText&quot;:&quot;&quot;}">
```

So the generated JSON string seems to be fine. What else am I missing? Or isn't this possible at all?

Comment: Your submitting a form, not the json data and you cannot bind a complex object to a `string`

Comment: If you want to bind to `SearchOptions`, then you need a form control for each property in the model - e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="SearchText" ... />`

Comment: Doesn't controller bind the parameter in json format to the object with the similar schema?

Comment: No, a form will submit as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. - i.e name/value pairs. Your using `JSON.stringify()` which means you would need to use ajax and set `contentType" application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Hmmm, that's too bad. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I ended up doing. After making sure that there's no way to make form encoding "application/json" with normal form submit (contrary to what people say in many SO threads) I decided to use Request.Form to reach the json object constructed on the client side. As @Stephen Muecke stated, I had an option to provide all the input values as parameters, but there are way to many fields and I don't want to mess my action method with lot's of parameters. There's actually a better way than all the rest, which is to pass it inside a ViewModel, but the thing is, in my situation I can't do that because I can't pass a separate ViewModel to a _layout(master) page. So here's the code finally:

```
public ActionResult(){
  var searchOptionsJson = Request.Form["searchOptions"];
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchOptionsJson))            
      SearchOptions searchOptions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchOptions>(searchOptionsJson);
}
```